# removeClass() doesn't remove class on element of wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I can't remove 'open' class and close the popped up window on wordpress site. I have had no problem with add/removeClass in jQuery. Wordpress is new to me.

Selector 'search-close' is correct and responding as I changed jQuery `.removeClass()` by `.css("background", "red")`. Only `.removeClass()` doesn't work or remove the class 'open' from element selected.

```
<div class = "search-button">
   <div id="fullscr">
      <div class="close-button">X</div>
        <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="<?php echo...
        </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
#fullscr.open {

    opacity: 1;
}
#fullscr {
z-index: 100;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;

    opacity: 0;
}
div.close-button{
display:block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    background:green;
    &:hover {
        opacity:0.6;
    }
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('search-button').on('click', function(){

     $('#fullscr').addClass('open');

});
$('.close-button').on('click', function(){
     $('#fullscr').removeClass(); or .removeClass('open');
// $(this).css("background","blue"); is working but why removeClass has no action ??

});
```

`.close-button onclick` should remove popped up full window with search form. How to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should read `$('#fullscr').removeClass('open');` but assuming you had that code written correctly, you still have an issue. You have an onclick handler for `.search-button` that adds the class 'open' when clicked. The `.close-button` is a descendent of the '.search-button' so event bubbling might mean that every time you click the close button, the open class is removed and immediately added because the onclick handler for `.search-button` is also executing.

I would suggest moving the popup so it is not a descendant of the search button, but you can just add `e.stopPropagation()` to the close button event handler to stop event bubbling from occurring as in this example snippet using your code.

```js
$('.search-button').on('click', function() {
  $('#fullscr').addClass('open');
});

$('.close-button').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  $('#fullscr').removeClass('open');
});
```

```css
#fullscr.open {
  opacity: 1;
}

#fullscr {
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
}

div.close-button {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  background: green;
  &:hover {
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-button">
  Search
  <div id="fullscr">
    <div class="close-button">X</div>
    <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form">
      <input name="keywords" />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I removed search-button out of nesting, to have no descendants. It works. Good answer about event bubble.